# Unexpected execution of "all" target in my makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile, target, automatic-variable

I've a makefile that is suppose to repeat an execution of a c code (BootstrapCL.c) one time for each file.csv in the directory. For each execution it should give in input to the c code (as argv) 2 string: the name, with and without extention, of the input csv file used in the current execution.
This is the makefile content:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.csv)
BINS := $(SRCS:%.csv=%)

all: ${BINS}

%: BootstrapCL.c
    gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
    ./BootstrapCL $@.csv $@
```

The problem is that, after the execution of all the group of csv file (iI'd like to execute only the target inside ${BINS} list) , it also run a last execution with "all" target. Of course I don't have any all.csv file in my folder; I think I'm using $@ in the wrong way but I don't understand why and how to fix the issue, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a slightly different take on the solution then Beta's:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.csv)
BINS := $(SRCS:%.csv=%)

# All rule - requires binaries to be generated. This does not generate anything, therefore it is PHONY
.PHONY: all
all: ${BINS}

# Generates the binaries - requires BootstrapCL exe to be generated first
${BINS}: BootstrapCL
    ./BootstrapCL $@.csv $@

# Generates BootstrapCL
BootstrapCL:
    gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
```

From what I can tell - you need to compile BootstrapCL.c once to generate BootstrapCL executable. Then using that you genetate multiple binaries - one for eacn .csv file.

So in reverse:

- You have an `all` target that requires the BINS.
- You have a `BINS` target that generates the BINs, but first requires BootstrapCL - this will run once for each .csv file.
- You have a `BootstrapCL` target that generates the BootstrapCL executable - this will run just once.

Comment: why BootstrapCL target will run just once in this way?

Comment: Because the rule to create `BootstrapCL` is defined - so once the file `BootstrapCL` exists make will see that it exists and will not try to create it again (if the time stamp is newer then the source file). That is a key feature of makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no *recipe* for `all`, and a rule for `%` which matches *anything.* When Make has finished with the prerequisites (`${BINS}`), it tries to build `all`, goes looking for a recipe that fits, and finds `%`.

There are (at least) two ways to solve the problem. The quick and dirty way is to add a (null) recipe for `all`:

```
all: ${BINS}
    @:
```

Onother way, in my opinion better, is to tighten the second rule:

```
BINS := $(SRCS:%.csv=%.phony)

all: ${BINS}

%.phony: BootstrapCL.c
    gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
    ./BootstrapCL $*.csv $*
```

Just to be tidy, I suggest you also add the line:

```
.PHONY: $(BINS)
```

To let Make know that the `.phony` targets are not real files to be built.

Some other small improvements are possible. I would think about `BootstrapCL` and whether it produces a file that could be used as a real target.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Beta; it helps me to better understand what's going on; now I've only one doubt. "When Make has finished with the prerequisites (${BINS}), it tries to build all". But all doesn't have a recipe, so why make assign to "all" the recipe of another target (${BINS})?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` rule is too general and catches everything, even attempt to rebuild the Makefile itself. Moreover it compiles `BootstrapCL` every time, which seems unnecessary:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
./BootstrapCL Makefile.csv Makefile
gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
./BootstrapCL foo.csv foo
gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
./BootstrapCL bar.csv bar
gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
./BootstrapCL all.csv all
```

I would make use of pattern rule for binary generation, as this also will rebuild the binary should the .csv file change. I would also separate `BootstrapCL` generation to a different rule to only compile it once, but keep it on the dependency list for the targets to regenerate them if `BootstrapCL` changes:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRCS := $(wildcard *.csv)
BINS := $(SRCS:%.csv=%)

all: ${BINS}

BootstrapCL: BootstrapCL.c
        gcc -Wall $< -lm -o $@

%: %.csv BootstrapCL
        ./BootstrapCL $< $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c -lm -o BootstrapCL
./BootstrapCL foo.csv foo
./BootstrapCL bar.csv bar
```